# Creating and Storing an Dynamic array Android

Tags: android

```
for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){  
    arr[i] = finalsum;
    System.out.println("--->aa"+arr[i]);
  }
```

using this funcationality, array value is overriden. so, please tell me proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Arrays.fill(int[] array, int value)`, like this:

```
Arrays.fill(arr,finalsum);
```

For sorting use `Arrays.sort(int[] array)`

```
Arrays.sort(arr);
```

Comment: What did you try? Please post your code, and also post what your expected output was.

Comment: insort my requirement is create array and store value. but vaule is overwrite.

Comment: So what i understand is you want the sort output to be stored in another array and not the same one right?

Comment: no my finalsum value is double so, first create array then store

Comment: So why don't you create a double array? Like `double[] finalSum = new double[arr.length];`?

Comment: Like this: `Arrays.fill(finalSumDoubleArray,finalsumValue);`